# How to import stylesheet in angular with id attribute?

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to integrate a bootstrap dashboard template into an Angular8 project. but I'm getting the `resource not found` error when I link the css file in `index.html`,

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/css/theme.min.css" id="stylesheetLight">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/css/theme-dark.min.css" id="stylesheetDark">
```

In my template they used an id attribute in each stylesheet. Because of this id attribute (`id="stylesheetLight"`), I'm not able to import it into; neither `style.css` nor `angular.json`. And without specifying the id, the design will be broken.

The error I'm getting when I import in index.html:
[image]

How can solve the resource not found error? Or is there any way that I can specify the id in `style.css` as `@import` ?

Comment: I think your design is flawed, if your design is breaking without specifying an ID attribute. I can't think of any scenario, where I would need an ID attributre on a css style link.

Comment: The design is working fine with id as it is. When I tried to change the id in template, it's not working. Also I can't specify the id, when integrating with angular.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it in **angular.json** file:

```
"options": {
  ...
  "styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "src/assets/css/theme.min.css"
    "src/assets/css/theme-dark.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "assets": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

In Angular, adding style sheet like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/css/theme.min.css" id="stylesheetLight">` isn't the correct way

Comment: How can I specify the id? the design is broken without `id="stylesheetLight"`

Comment: Where are you using the id

Comment: Even without angular, the template not working without `id="stylesheetLight"`, It's a template using bootstrap4 and jquery.

Comment: It would be better to use a work around by using class name of respective themes instead of id

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, reason why I want to add id is because i want to do this from https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

```
<link id="themeAsset" rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/my/theme-name.css">

function changeTheme(themeName) {
  document.getElementById('themeAsset').href = `/path/to/my/${themeName}.css`;
}
```

so i could change style for whole app styles by click instead of adding classes to every component

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stylesheet, e.g. "shared.css", and add it to `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/shared.css"
        ],
```

and use your styles conditionally:

```
[class.my-class]="foo=='light'"
```